# Multiple Screen Support Issue with 510 x 140 Original Image

Tags: android, imageview, android-screen-support

Please how can I decide what my android image dimensions should be for multiple screen support. I have a rectangle PNG image for my splash screen with a 510 x 140 dimension.

But the recommended dimensions I have seen online for MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHPDI and XXXHDPI are square shaped and will ruin how the original image fits to my splash screen.

Is there a way I can figure out much more reasonable dimension scales for a 510 x 140 rectangular image that won't make ridiculous differences?

Thanks.

Comment: we have to look at .svg file format. Vector graphic image great irrespective of dimensions

Comment: Try to figure out the relative dimensions relatively to the suggested squares. i.e.: your 510x140 would perfectly fit in a 512x512 square, either vertically or horizontally. Then it's just a matter of doing some trivial proportions.

Comment: Thank you I think that makes some sense.